# If time was speeding up, would it look like inflation?

Tags: cosmology, time, relativity, cosmological-inflation

The rate at which time passes depends on the gravitational potential.

From Wikipedia: "This is a direct result of gravitational time dilation - if one is outside of an isolated gravitational source, the rate at which time passes increases as one moves away from that source. "

From this, I gather that the rate at which time passes can in fact accelerate or decelerate. Most likely, this is impossible to observe locally.

If an observer is moving toward a gravitational source, such as the Shapley Supercluster, the rate at which time passes for them will be accelerating with respect to others.

This means that when we observe light emitted from others, this light will be frequency shifted - usually called gravitational redshift or Einstein Shift.

Is this assertion correct:

- If two observers, are moving together in parallel into a region of space with a higher gravitational potential, they will still see frequency shift on light emitted by each other. The amount of shift corresponds to the distance to the observed object, much like Hubbles Law - and the cause of this effect is that due to the speed of light, we are looking back in time.
- Hubbles Law is sometimes explained by dark energy, but it could also be explained by an ongoing and universal change in the rate at which time passes - similar to if the entire universe was moving toward a region with higher or lower gravitational potential?

Comment: The speed of light depends on how fast time passes. nope,  it doesn't

Comment: @TáMéCeart Yep it does. 300000 km per second - and this is universally constant. So, if we see light traveling 300000 km from A to B near a black hole, it will take longer time as seen from our point of view. This is because time passes faster for us than for them.

Comment: If by "subjective" you mean local time in relativity then the speed of light does not depend on it, it is the same in all local frames. You should use the [relativistic law for adding velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_relativity) instead of the classical one.  I am not sure what "time accelerating" means to you, but whatever it is "time universally accelerating" makes no sense in relativity because there is no "universal time".

Comment: @Conifold The speed of light is the same in all local frames. I am saying that you don't stay in a frame of reference over time, time is a coordinate as well. If time has a velocity, and the velocity of time is accelerating I believe it would directly imply cosmic inflation.

Comment: What you are saying is that time changes over time, this is either circular or introduces "meta-time" with respect to which "this time" varies. Well, local times already vary with respect to each other, so what you want is a privileged frame of "true time" with respect to which our local time varies. As I said this is ruled out by relativity, and so far is too obscure to imply something, inflation or not.

Comment: You say that time is speeding up... relative to what?

Comment: @probably_someone relative to itself at an earlier time. Point is that time for us locally passes faster than time for "them" - because when we look far away, we also look back in time.

Comment: @Conifold This does not require a "true" frame. If time accelerates, then it means that - as we look one light year away, we have to take into account not only the distance, but also that time for that object passes more slowly. This is of course relativistic. If that object looks at us, they would be working at a higher clock rate than us.

Comment: Suppose you were in a windowless box. Is there any experiment you could perform that could tell you that time was speeding up?

Comment: @probably_someone If the box was big enough (galactic scale) or if the instruments were sensitive enough. If time was accelerating, you would expect redshift for very distant objects - but that is currently explained by dark energy... I'll have to think more about it.

Comment: @probably_someone If time was accelerating, all other objects would become redshifted - but the amount of redshift would depend on their distance from the observer. The red shift would seem to be accelerating. But there should be redshift even for objects only a few meters apart. I guess this could be simulated quite easily.

Comment: You do realize that redshift is a consequence of objects *moving away from each other*, right? It has nothing to do with the "speed of time". So an object a few meters away that isn't moving will not be redshifted.

Comment: @probably_someone You also get redshift if light was emitted at a lower frequency due to a lower clock rate, relative to our more accelerated clock.

Comment: @probably_someone I have been thinking, and if we take a hypothetical spaceship and travel toward a distant redshifted object - even if we travel at constant velocity - that star should display acceleratingly decreasing redshift, as seen from the spaceship. I don't know how this could be experimentally tested though.

Comment: Please *define* the notion of "speed of time" within the post. Generally, "speed of X" means "rate of change of X with respect to time". The rate of change of time with respect to time is trivially 1.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm deducing from the fact that Einstein Shift exists, that there that time has a sort of "velocity". The rate at which a caecium atomic clock ticks is different and different gravitational potentials. It is a recursive definition, and it is 1 in relation to the local frame of reference, but if you look at time as a coordinate, obviously you are continously changing your frame of reference as time passes. `velocity-of-time-now` > `velocity-of-time-momentarily-ago`